# Simple syntax help for an IF statement

Tags: php

Hello I have a foreach loop that assigns values to the following code

```
${'varimages' . $image_count} = $images;

// outputs for image_count = 1, $varimages1 = a string
```

However, I want to make an IF statement to check something. The "correct" form should be below but I have errors for the presence of "`{`" and "`}`"

```
if (${'varimages' . $image_count} == ${'vartitle' . $image_count}) 
{ echo "ok"; } else { echo "not ok"; }
```

How can I rewrite that statement correctly? Thank u!

Comment: Why aren't you using arrays?

Comment: @konforce: +10000, but i can only give you 1

Comment: @konforce @prodigitalson Hi thanks for your answer... Well I have already built the script and this is my last modification. I guess arrays will be my choice if I can't find a solution. But there should be!
Can you give me an example ?

Comment: put all the code, this works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: @Itay's right, this does work if I just test with `$image_count` == 1 after manually assigning `$varimages1` and `$vartitle1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using arrays, it would be:

```
if($varimages[$image_count] == $vartitle[$image_count])
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. Is there a workaround for my case?

Comment: @Mairy - your code works...u should put more of it, it seems your issue is somewhere else. Also, add the php version u use.